# SQL Error (102): Incorrect syntax near '>'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some real trouble with this CASE statement...
It says I get an error near > which seems to point to the 3rd line where its checking > 15. However I don't see anything wrong with this query.

I tried searching around on google and here and didn't see anyone with this exact problem, hopefully you can point it out.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 15 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 30 THEN '15+'
    ELSE DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 30 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 60 THEN '30+'
    ELSE DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 60 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 90 THEN '60+'
    ELSE DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 90 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 120 THEN '90+'
    ELSE '120+'
END AS 'Days', 
C1.CallID AS 'Ticket#', A1.WhoAcknow AS 'Acknowledged By', C1.RecvdDate AS 'Received On', C1.Category, COUNT(*) As Assignments 

FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1 
LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID 
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 15 AND C1.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' AND 
A1.Resolution = '' AND (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') 
GROUP BY C1.CallID, A1.WhoAcknow, C1.RecvdDate, C1.Category 
ORDER BY C1.RecvdDate ASC
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `CASE` expression. When using multiple conditions, you use `WHEN` instead of `ELSE`. `ELSE` should only be used once.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 15 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 30 THEN '15+'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 30 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 60 THEN '30+'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 60 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 90 THEN '60+'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 90 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 120 THEN '90+'
    ELSE '120+'
END AS 'Days'...
```

Comment: Why not use Between? `WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 16 AND 30` is much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the syntax wrong; you can't use multiple ELSE clauses - it should be multiple WHENs:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 15 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 30 THEN '15+'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 30 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 60 THEN '30+'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 60 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 90 THEN '60+'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 90 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 120 THEN '90+'
    ELSE '120+'
END AS 'Days'
```

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is your formatting of the CASE statement, I put your query is SSMS and fixed it this way, and it passes validation:

you can only use 1 ELSE clause per CASE statement

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 15 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 30 THEN '15+'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 30 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 60 THEN '30+'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 60 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 90 THEN '60+'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 90 AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 120 THEN '90+'
        ELSE '120+'
    END AS 'Days', 
    C1.CallID AS 'Ticket#', A1.WhoAcknow AS 'Acknowledged By', C1.RecvdDate AS 'Received On', C1.Category, COUNT(*) As Assignments 

    FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1 
    LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 15 AND C1.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' AND 
    A1.Resolution = '' AND (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') 
    GROUP BY C1.CallID, A1.WhoAcknow, C1.RecvdDate, C1.Category 
    ORDER BY C1.RecvdDate ASC
```